# not able to perfom actions on mongodb fs when using a flask celery task

Tags: mongodb, flask, redis, celery

I am trying to add the functionality to the task "delete_conversations_and_child_messages_after_task" in my flask app so that it can delete some files from the mongodb file system but I am getting some errors.
these are the relevant files::

```
# app.py

from app_config import create_app
from services.celery.celery_instance import celery  # do not remove
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
import os, nltk


from services.apis.mongodb import MongoDBConnector
from services.celery.celery_config import init_celery
from celery.schedules import crontab



def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 1000 * 1024 * 1024  # 1000 MB

    init_celery(app)
    load_dotenv()

    nltk.download('punkt')

    CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})

    app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ.get('JWT_KEY')
    mongo_connector = MongoDBConnector(app)
    app.config['MONGO_CONNECTOR'] = mongo_connector



    return app


nltk.download('punkt')

app = create_app()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

```
# services.apis.mongodb.py

import os
import pymongo
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine

class MongoDBConnector:
    def __init__(self, app):
        mongo_username = os.environ.get('MONGO_USERNAME')
        mongo_password = os.environ.get('MONGO_USERNAME_PASWORD')
        mongo_database = os.environ.get('MONGO_DATABASE')
        mongo_url_at = os.environ.get('MONGO_URL')

        mongo_url = f"mongodb+srv://{mongo_username}:{mongo_password}@{mongo_url_at}/{mongo_database}?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
        self.client = pymongo.MongoClient(mongo_url)
        mongo_cluster = os.environ.get('MONGO_CLUSTER')
        self.db = self.client[mongo_cluster]

        app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {
            'db': mongo_database,
            'host': mongo_url,
            'retryWrites': True,
        }
        self.db_engine = MongoEngine(app)
```

```
# services.celery.celery_config.py

from services.celery.celery_instance import celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

# scheduled tasks
from services.celery.scheduled_tasks.delete_conversations_and_child_messages_after_ import delete_conversations_and_child_messages_after_task



def init_celery(app):
    app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://redis:6379/0'
    app.config['result_backend'] = 'redis://redis:6379/0'

    app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://redis:6379/0'
    app.config['result_backend'] = 'redis://redis:6379/0'
    app.config['CELERYD_TASK_LOG_SUCCESS'] = False
    app.config['beat_schedule'] = {
        'delete_old_conversations': {
            'task': 'services.celery.scheduled_tasks.delete_conversations_and_child_messages_after_.delete_conversations_and_child_messages_after_task',
         # 'schedule': crontab(hour=0, minute=0),  # runs daily at midnight
         'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),  # runs every minute
        },  
    }
    celery.conf.broker_url = app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL']
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
```

```
# services.celery.celery_instance.py

from celery import Celery

celery = Celery()
```

```
# services.celery.tasks.delete_conversations_and_child_messages_after_.py

from gridfs import GridFS
from flask import current_app
from app_config import create_app
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from models.conversation import Conversation
from models.conversation_message import ConversationMessage

from services.celery.celery_instance import celery

from services.redis.initialize_redis import get_redis_connection

r = get_redis_connection()



@celery.task(bind=True)
def delete_conversations_and_child_messages_after_task(self):
    app = create_app()
    with app.app_context():
        cutoff_date = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=0)
        connector = current_app.config['MONGO_CONNECTOR']
        fs = GridFS(connector.db)

        # Get the list of IDs for conversations that need to be deleted.
        conversations_to_delete = Conversation.objects(created_on__lt=cutoff_date)

        # Delete associated data files in GridFS
        for conversation in conversations_to_delete:
            if conversation.extracted_data_file_id:
                try:
                    # This deletes both the chunks and the file from GridFS
                    fs.delete(conversation.extracted_data_file_id)
                except:
                    # Handle any errors that might arise from trying to delete a non-existent file
                    pass

        # Get the list of IDs for conversations that need to be deleted.
        conversation_ids_to_delete = [conv.id for conv in conversations_to_delete]

        # Delete associated messages
        ConversationMessage.objects(conversation_id__in=conversation_ids_to_delete).delete()

        # Delete the conversations
        Conversation.objects(id__in=conversation_ids_to_delete).delete()
```

these are the errors im getting::

```
errors:
     Traceback (most recent call last):
docwise-backend-web-1     |   File "/app/app.py", line 3, in <module>
docwise-backend-web-1     |     from app_config import create_app
docwise-backend-web-1     |   File "/app/app_config.py", line 19, in <module>
docwise-backend-web-1     |     from services.celery.celery_config import init_celery
docwise-backend-web-1     |   File "/app/services/celery/celery_config.py", line 7, in <module>
docwise-backend-web-1     |     from services.celery.scheduled_tasks.delete_conversations_and_child_messages_after_ import delete_conversations_and_child_messages_after_task
docwise-backend-web-1     |   File "/app/services/celery/scheduled_tasks/delete_conversations_and_child_messages_after_.py", line 5, in <module>
docwise-backend-web-1     |     from app_config import create_app
docwise-backend-web-1     | ImportError: cannot import name 'create_app' from partially initialized module 'app_config' (most likely due to a circular import) (/app/app_config.py)
```

I understand the error but i dont know how to fix it.
i didnt find any other stackoverflow questions that tried to perform actions on the mongodb fs.

the setup i have works perfectly until i try to perform actions on the  mongodb fs.

how should i set up celery so i dont have this issue or how can i fix it?

Comment: Did you try removing that import statement `from app_config import create_app`? You define another `create_app` in `app.py`. And could you please describe your project structure?